iPadOS elevated tab bar doesn't change appearance for unselected items
In the new iPadOS18+ elevated tab bar, no matter what i do, i cannot change the color of unselected icons... only the selected icon color reflects the UITabBarController view's tintColor
no matter if

setting the UITabBarAppearance for the stackedLayoutAppearance (or other appearances)
setting in XCode interface builder (with or without custom appereance)
setting the tabBar appearence directly

code
let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
tabBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
tabBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    
tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.green]
tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.iconColor = UIColor.green
tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.iconColor = UIColor.red
    
UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance
UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance
    
UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = .black

tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance
tabBar.standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance

